# how can I trigger an angular change event with a jquery UI slider?

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs

Originally, I had a text input setup with a ng-model attribute, so that when changing its value, it would trigger something else on the page that was utilizing that model attribute.  I have replaced that text input with a jQuery UI slider, and am curious what the correct or "angular" way to interact with this element so that the slider's change event / function can delegate directly to angular and accomplish the same sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the ui-slider component of angular-ui](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-slider/blob/master/src/slider.js) to see a solution for your situation.